# Using the Internet of Operating System 1 by Operating System 2 in VMware

Tags: networking, vmware

I have two operating systems on VMware:

- OS 1: Windows.
- OS 2: Linux.

OS 1 is connected to the Internet using a dongle modem. I want OS 2 to use the internet of OS1 VMware. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set up networking between the systems using vmware networking options (google), tell OS to "share the internet" to OS 2, and make OS 1 use OS 2 as default gateway.

There are plenty of variations for this, like having the vmware host the internet connection, and then making both the OS use the host as default gateway.

Comment: dirkt@dirkt Your answer is very general. If possible, present the procedure in detail. Thanks.

Comment: Since your host OS is Windows, you can install routing role and configure OS as router and DHCP server to assign IP to OS2 so that it can connect to internet. As an example: 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-sg/how10169/configuring-windows-server-2012-r2-as-a-router?lang=en
You can read about Software-defined networking on Windows here: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/software-defined-networking-sdn-stack-in-the-windows-server-2016